# How to check the similarity between two transition matrixes

Tags: scikit-learn, similarity, distribution

I have two transition matrixes in which the probabilities for the transition between each `from` state to each `to` states are recorded. For instance

`trans_mat1` is

```
      s1    s2    s3    
s1    0.23  0.15  0.26
s2    0.82  0.01  0.01
s3    0.27  0.78  0.08
```

`trans_mat2` is

```
      s1    s2    s3    
s1    0.05  0.66  0.44
s2    0.57  0.70  0.12
s3    0.71  0.01  0.28
```

These are dummy transition matrixes to show an MWE. I am confused how to check if these two transition matrixes show the same transition pribabilities given that `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are same in both matrixes?

Can I treat them as a single probability distribution vector and calculate KL divergence using `scipy.stats.entropy` function ?

Comment: maybe here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18457/comparing-transition-matrices-for-markov-chains?